# Kendo Share DataSource Between ComboBox and TreeList

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

My application has a Kendo TreeList and a Kendo ComboBox. The DataSource for the TreeList could also be used for the ComboBox. If this is possible it would prevent me from having to run the same query twice.

This is further complicated, it seems, by my TreeList using a transport for CRUD operations.

Example of my shared DataSource:

```
        var sharedDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: function (e) {
                    webService.getData(arg1, arg2).then(function (response) {
                        e.success(response.data);
                    }, function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
                }
            }
        });

       sharedDataSource.read();
```

The transport part of my TreeList:

```
transport: {
    read: function (e) {
       e.success(sharedDataSource);//sharedDataSource has NO data here. That's the problem
    }
}
```

ComboBox:

```
            $("#comboBox").width(250).kendoComboBox({
                dataTextField: "name",
                dataValueField: "id",
                dataSource: sharedDataSource//The comboBox is launched via a click after the page loads and DOES have data here
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

[`DataSource.read()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-read) is an async method. Data isn't loaded yet when TreeList is being initialized, therefore it will be empty.

Using `read` method with Promise resolving should help:

```
sharedDataSource.read().then(function () {
    // TreeList init

    // ComboBox init
});
```

Since TreeList has no paging or grouping, (assuming you load all treeitems at once), you could use [`DataSource.view()` method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-view) to extract data and avoid undesired remote requests.

```
// TreeList and ComboBox transports

transport: {
    read: function (e) {
       e.success(sharedDataSource.view());
    }
}
```

**Dojo demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@msagi/EnEnI** (with fake remote call)